# Android account manager - Layout of account menu

Tags: android, android-preferences, accountmanager

I would like to create an account menu like dropbox but can´t find out how to do it.

I read through all documentation but its lacking. Can someone give an example?

**Try to achieve:**

a) [image: Menu]
b) [image: Dropbox account menu]

Eg. If you hit dropbox icon in the list on a) you continue to b) which just shows an dropbox account. No extra steps, great!

**Don't want:** (which I have now)

c) [image]
d) [image: Preference with settings]

If the user press `Udinic` icon in the list c) he will be redirected to d) which shows general settings for `Udinic`. When user presses `udi@udinic.com` it will show a screen corresponding to b) above. ***I want to remove this extra step***

The above example is produced by using a preference setting xml file according to documentation. (Like code below but not this specific code)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="UDINIC Preferences" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:title="Use debug server"
        android:key="isDebug"
        android:summary="Connecting to a debug server instead of staging server."/>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:title="Debug address"
        android:key="debugAddress" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

In authenticator.xml from this example remove `android:accountPreferences="@xml/prefs"`